# How do you express in english the idea of noticing something

Tags: word-choice, writing-style

I'm writing an essay, and I'd like to write at the beginning of the text that it is important to notice the ambiguity of the question I'm asked. How can I do that properly in english?

I'm my language, I would have said :

"We remark".
Or :
"One should notice that..."

thank you!

Comment: If you just mention the thing itself, it is obvious that you noticed it or you would not be mentioning it. "The question is ambiguous but I am answering it as ..." And the fact that this opens your essay, shows that it is important too.

Comment: well putting the thing that way makes also sens

Comment: In English it is perfectly normal to say "One should notice that...", "We notice that..." or even "You will (or should) notice that.." but "We remark..." is not normally used to open a piece of writing. It would be understood but would sound odd.

Comment: This is commonly shortened to just *Note that . . .*

Comment: *I would point out that* you're not talking about noticing something but about getting others to notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It should  be  noted that..." is conventionally used in more formal, third-person writing. "Note that" serves almost the same purpose, but is more imperative. Phrasing it  as a (strong) suggestion is politer than ordering the reader to notice something, but it's a very subtle connotation that makes no real difference to the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Why not something shorter like "Note that ..." Please [edit] this to give some reasons for your suggestion.